# Change of variables for momenta

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, calculus, wigner-transform

[http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/~pikovsky/teaching/stud_seminar/Wigner_function.pdf](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/%7Epikovsky/teaching/stud_seminar/Wigner_function.pdf)

From the Appendix in the above PDF (page 945), below equation (A3) the following expressions are given:

$$
u = p' - p'' 
$$
$$
v = p' + p''
$$
$$
dudv = 2dp'dp'',
$$
where $p'$ and $p''$ are momenta. When I try to calculate $dudv$ I get:

$$du = dp' - dp''$$

$$dv = dp' + dp''$$

$$ dudv = (dp' - dp'')(dp' + dp'') = (dp')^2 - (dp'')^2 - dp''dp' + dp'dp'' = 0.$$
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to obtain the referenced result in the linked paper. The first is to realize that they are performing a change of variables in a 2-dimensional integral. when doing so, we always pick up a factor which is the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation:
$$
\iint f(x,y)dxdy=\iint f(x(u,v), y(u,v))|J|dudv
$$
where $|J|$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix whose components are the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $u$ and $v$.

Turning to this particular problem, the Jacobian of this transformation may be computed to be
$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
whose determinant we can check to be $|J|=2$, hence the result presented in the paper.

It should also be noted that there is a way to compute the change of variables by manipulations similar to the ones you have shown in the question. In one-dimensional integrals, nothing about what you have done would need to change, but in two or more dimensions, manipulations of this kind must treat the "product" of differentials as a wedge product (which is related to differential forms being the correct objects to integrate over on any manifold). With the wedge product we would write $dudv$ as $du\wedge dv$, and note that the wedge product anticommutes, meaning $du\wedge dv=-dv\wedge du$. Going ahead with this, we would indeed find
$$
du\wedge dv=(dp^\prime-dp^{\prime\prime})\wedge(dp^\prime+dp^{\prime\prime})=dp^\prime\wedge dp^{\prime}-dp^{\prime\prime}\wedge dp^{\prime\prime} -dp^{\prime\prime}\wedge dp^\prime+dp^\prime\wedge dp^{\prime\prime}=2d p^\prime\wedge dp^{\prime\prime}
$$
where I have used the anti-commutivity to change the $-dp^{\prime\prime}\wedge dp^\prime$ into $+dp^\prime\wedge dp^{\prime\prime}$ and also to conclude that anything wedged with itself must be zero.

By either of these methods, the desired result may be obtained. The key is that integrals of dimension higher than one work slightly differently than our experience with one-dimensional integrals might suggest.